# How can i dynamicly map column names on import

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my situation, i am importing from multiple data sources into my json backend.

The mapping file will look something like this sample below. So the question is how could i go about it to effectively look up the mapping on an import from this json file and use it when to import the data into my backend. So the concept is to pass 2 objects to my function, the mapping file and the json object which holds the data from the vendor. Then i have to use the mapping and loop thru data to create an object / doc and insert in my backend with correct mappings.

```
{
    "vendor" : "ABCVendor",
    "version" : "2.01",
    "mappings" : [
        {   "fieldName" : "fName",
            "dbName" : "FirstName",
            "required" : true,
            "type" : "string"
        },
                {   "fieldName" : "mName",
            "dbName" : "MiddleName",
            "required" : false,
            "type" : "string"
        },
                {   "fieldName" : "lName",
            "dbName" : "LastName",
            "required" : true,
            "type" : "string"
        }
    
    ]
}
```

Here is what the input would look like

```
{
        "fname" : "Steve",
        "mname" : "T",
        "lname" : "Miller"
}
```

Ad here is what i would like to get out

```
{
        "FirstName" : "Steve",
        "MiddleName" : "T",
        "LastName" : "Miller"
}
```

Comment: Could we get the desired output, there are multiple ways to do what you are asking.

Comment: Updated Question with sample for both Input and desired Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, if the insert is always the same.

this may not be the most performant way to do it though.

```js
"use strict";
const fileConfig = {
    "vendor": "ABCVendor",
    "version": "2.01",
    "mappings": [
        {
            "fieldName": "fName",
            "dbName": "FirstName",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "mName",
            "dbName": "MiddleName",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "lName",
            "dbName": "LastName",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]
};
const funcInput = {
    "fName": "Steve",
    "mName": "T",
    "lName": "Miller"
};
function change(config, input) {
    const result = {};
    config.mappings.forEach((fe) => {
        result[fe.dbName] = input[fe.fieldName];
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(change(fileConfig, funcInput))
```

Comment: That is so simple but so perfect, not to be greedy here but since you are looping thru the mapping it will look for every field even if it is not defined and create then a undefined. Can i omit any of the undefined fields from being added to result ?

Comment: i know i can use a simple Object.Keys afterwards like Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] === undefined && delete obj[key]) but wonder if i can do it before i even add to the result

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all with `reduce` (although there does appear to be a casing difference in your mapping vs your object which ive used `toLowerCase` to get aeround - maybe uunncessary if that was just a typo on your part)

```js
const config = {
    "vendor" : "ABCVendor",
    "version" : "2.01",
    "mappings" : [
        {   "fieldName" : "fName",
            "dbName" : "FirstName",
            "required" : true,
            "type" : "string"
        },
                {   "fieldName" : "mName",
            "dbName" : "MiddleName",
            "required" : false,
            "type" : "string"
        },
                {   "fieldName" : "lName",
            "dbName" : "LastName",
            "required" : true,
            "type" : "string"
        }
    
    ]
}
const input = {
        "fname" : "Steve",
        "mname" : "T",
        "lname" : "Miller"
}

const result = config.mappings.reduce( 
        (acc, {fieldName, dbName}) => ({...acc, [dbName]: input[fieldName.toLowerCase()]})
    ,{})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: The problem with Casings can happen as i do not control vendor field names in Some Cases they can be Upper, lower mixed or even have spaces

Comment: @SamS87 upper/lower mixed I think your fine, just make sure everything is the same. Spaces... well you could just remove all spaces.